# Fingerprint matching in mobile devices (coding in OpenCV, deployment in Android)

Tags: opencv

I am intending to do my mainstream project in image processing domain. My project's aim is to enable user with finger print security in mobile devices. It involves:

1. Reading the fingerprint from user through mobile phone.
2. Matching the fingerprint image obtained with those available in the
   database.

I am interested in coding my project in OpenCV and deploying in Android. I need clarifications on few of the following things:

1. Is this project feasible?
2. Is OpenCV apt for this project? (considered Matlab, but it doesn't have portability to Android)
3. Eclipse or Visual Studio?, which will be more suitable (considering the deployment in Android)

I am a beginner and need to learn OpenCV, so please guide me how to start my project (what are the tools, books for reference and the IDE's, SDK's to be used?)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, for sure, but not easy.
2. OpenCV. Lots of stuff: http://opencv.org/
3. Eclipse, taking into account that you will be deploying it on Android.

Good luck!

Comment: SSV, I am interested in your project, maybe I'd like to help you. Are you interested?

Comment: @DídacPérez : Hi can you help me in OpenCV, I have posted the question here but am not able to find an answer http://answers.opencv.org/question/18436/what-to-do-with-dmatch-value/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily work with OpenCV. Its not hard.

Learning Android portion - to me is the challenging part. If you want to use this finger recognition - you could do this by capturing an image from your front cam OR by using your back also (assuning you put a finger on the camera lens, while holding the phone).

Now to use this feature to unlock your phone - to me is a tough job. It involves more of android.

To start with - I would suggest you to build an app with a finger recognition algorithm. It should recognize your finger & may be take an action like display your name or something like this.

If you can do this.. the rest is all android, and how you play with android to get this to work.

I hope this helps and gives you a very high level answer.